# Regex to find and replace space between text in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

```
PolygonID   SubPolygonID    PointID Longitude   Latitude    AREA_1
1   1   1   103.58792099955456933   0.45318600043361812 Northern Sumatera
1   1   2       103.58810399989971529   0.44205199960015307 Northern Sumatera
1   1   3       103.58190199987745928   0.44590400006961772 Northern Sumatera
1   1   4       103.58061199974406463   0.45378900036212144 Northern Sumatera
1   1   5       103.58309900021873773   0.45947099978684491 Northern Sumatera
1   1   6       103.58792099955456933   0.45318600043361812 Northern Sumatera
1   2   1   103.57287600002746331   0.46851599961371448 Northern Sumatera
```

I recently work on txt polygon file which contains coordinates for specific points, but in the txt file, I have to adjust the alignment for the columns because several rows in the longitude columns haven't been aligned well. Actually I am expecting it to be :

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaiER.png)

I am thinking of using notepadd ++ find and replace by regex to sort this thing out but I can't find the correct syntax for finding the mistake pattern. I thought of using **(number)\t(number)\t(number)\t(number)** and replace it with **(number)\t(number)\t(number)\t\t(number)**
but I don't know how to write it in regex syntax.
Can anyone help me with the syntax or even have a better logic to solve this?

Comment: Shall the values be separated via `\t` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
(((?<=^|\s)[.\d]+)\s+)
```

This looks for digits or dots, followed by at least one whitespace assuring that what precedes is a whitespace or the beginning of the line. Afterwards, replace the groups with `$2\t`, see [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/dO6mP9/2).

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for X number of spaces and replace for the number that you want.

To specify how many spaces you want to look for in regex, you can do this.

```
...([[:blank:]]{x})...
```